Extending Matlab's pchip to 2D
In The Matlab Guide, chapter 3, section 4, Moler describes a piecewise cubic Hermite interpolator $i$ which

Never leaves the data bounds on each subinterval, e.g. $t \in [t_k, t_{k+1}] \implies i(t) \in [\min(i(t_k), i(t_{k+1})), \max(i(t_k), i(t_{k+1}))]$
Is monotone on each subinterval.
Is $C^{1}$ on its domain of definition.

Can these properties be extended to 2D interpolations on regular grids? If not, what literature exists on computationally efficient smooth interpolators that get as close to these properties?

There is no total ordering on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\geq 2$, so monotonicity condition will not generalize. But if you use a simple tensor product extension, properties 1 and 3 are not too difficult obtain and prove.
